# My Android Studio Gradle is not getting the plugin from maven central

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I tried to add smoothprogressbar library to my android project

I added these lines to my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    // of course, do not write x.x.x but the version number
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:0.5.2'
}
```

And when i sync the gradle its saying that 
Failed to find : com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:0.5.1

I tried putting mavenCentral() and maven url in build.gradle and other solutions which i found in stackoverflow but nothing seems to work.

**Edited :**

This is my full gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'
    compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.18.0-rc') {
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
        exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
    }
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    compile project(':library')
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52'
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.+'
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:0.5.2'
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        ...
    }
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ...
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah Actually this issue arises when we have some other repositories added into repositories block. I added jcenter() repository befor mavenCentral() so i couldnt able to load external maven dependencies. After removing that jcenter() from repositories block it started working. Check repositories block in your module and also main project build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. You should post more of your build.gradle script (in particular, how exactly you tried to put mavenCentral() in the script), but the gist is that you need the following *outside of the android {} block in the script* (and this is in addition to the similar code in the buildscript {} block):

```
buildscript {
    // ...
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:0.5.2'
}

android {
    // ...
}
```

Then re-sync your project with Gradle.

Comment: I followed the same structure but still its not working. I updated my question with full build.gradle code

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach:

```
compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:0.5.2@aar'
```